# ¿En que parte del modelo vista controlador va el formulario de login y por ende el el formulario de registro de usuarios?

Tags: php

Agradezco sus respuestas. Ya manejo algo de php pero sin usar clases. Ahora estoy tratando de aprender el modelo viista controlador y quiero saber eso.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta a alto nivel es:

En la vista iría el formulario visible al usuario, es decir el input text para escribir el usuario, el input password para escribir la contraseña, y el input button con un evento de JS, Llamada AJAX, o simplemente con un GET/POST REQUEST que mande los datos al controlador.
Además de las validaciones de JS que impidan dejar en blanco ambos campos, o reglas similares.

En el controlador, el tratamiento de los datos, es decir: saneamiento de carácteres por ejemplo).

En el modelo, la recepción de los datos desde el controlador y la consulta hacia la base de datos con el usuario y contraseña dados.

Las validaciones de los datos de la vista de JS, deberían ir además en el controlador, modelo y opcionalmente en la base de datos como un Trigger / Assertion.

Como ejemplo te puedo dejar este proyecto:
https://github.com/Reflej0/DesafioMVC

Esta basado en CodeIgniter, y con respecto al login:

DesafioMVC/application/views/usuarios/login.php

DesafioMVC/application/controllers/Usuarioc.php

DesafioMVC/application/models/usuarios_model.php

Cualquier información adicional, no dudes en consultar.

Comment: Juanjoo la cuestion es que me están pidiendo php sin usar nada relacionado con js. Se puede hacer solo usando $_REQUEST ?

Comment: Si, en caso que estés realizando la tarea en PHP Nativo, tenes que realizar algo como esto: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp
Tener un formulario y los inputs text/password dentro de el.
Al presionar el submit buttón, procesas los datos recibidos con $_REQUEST['nombre del campo']
Y seguís ya en el controlador correspondiente.